# Distributable database with my application

Tags: node.js, mongodb, node-webkit, database

I am creating a NodeJs Desktop application using node-webkit and right now using MongoDB as a database.
I want to distribute it as an executable where users will be able to use the application without installing the database by utilizing their own copy of local DB.
Is there a way i can make a local copy for their DB during the installation.
If it is not possible in MongoDB, what other DB should i use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well its based on your data needs, if you have large set of data you should use mongoDB otherwise there are lots of databases for your NWJS app.   check this link https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js/wiki/Save-persistent-data-in-app some of them are good enough to hold big data.  but personally i prefer sqlite3 with NWJS(there is a lot of hustle to install it for NWJS) sqlite can work with large data check [this](http://www.sqlite.org/limits.html) page for more info.

if you are going with mongoDB then you should download the the zip not the installer and pack it with your installer the you should be good to go.
by default mongoDB stores its data in `/data/db` but you can change it to your preferred location